# how to open an existing .xlsx file using apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

I have aproblem in apache poi.

The problem is, I want to open an existing .xlsx file using apache poi in my java program.while doing, java raising below mentioned exception...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 2 more
```

I am using excel 2003 and just convert my .xls to .xlsx(Excel 2007 workbook) file using saveas command in excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException on your class path.

You need xbean.jar or [one of these jars](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException)

Now also - accept some answers to your previous questions